# flash message in auth controller

Tags: laravel-5

I'm looking for better solution to show flash message after login/logout/register. These methods are stored in AuthController through trait AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers. My second condition is not to edit AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.

My actually hack is below, but i'm not happy for that.
Have you got better idea?

**app/http/controllers/auth/authcontroller.php**

```
public function postLoginwithFlash(Request $request)
{
return $this->postLogin($request)->with('flash_message','You are logged');
}
```

and **routes.php**

```
Route::post('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLoginWithFlash']);
```

and **views** ofc

```
@if (Session::has('flash_message'))
{{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'native' way to do it. Either way you will have to change/edit the route.

Either you implement everything in the routes.php, or do it the way you already proposed – create a new method in AuthController. Essentially, it's the same thing.

However, I would recommend you to do proper manual check instead of returning postLogin(), eg.:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
     // Authentication passed...
     return redirect()->route('dashboard');
} else {
     return redirect()->refresh()->with('error', 'Those are not correct credentials!');
}
```

This way, you can add different flash messages to success and error cases while your proposed code will show the same message irrespective of result.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the language file **./resources/lang/en/auth.php**, then change this line

```
'failed' => 'Your custom login error message',
```